# Creating a custom AMI from an AWS OpsWorks, Chef 12, Linux instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

**Does anyone have an set of instructions for creating an AWS AMI from a chef 12, Linux based OpsWorks instance?**

AWS publishes instructions on [Creating a Custom Linux AMI from an AWS OpsWorks Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workinginstances-custom-ami.html#workinginstances-custom-ami-create).  But it looks like they are out of date for Chef 12, Linux based OpsWorks stacks.

For example, they do not say you should remove the `/opt/chef` or `/var/chef` folders.

Here are the current instructions from AWS:

---

### Create a Custom Linux AMI from an AWS OpsWorks Instance

If you want to use a customized AWS OpsWorks Linux instance to create an AMI, you should be aware that every Amazon EC2 instance created by OpsWorks includes a unique identity. If you create a custom AMI from such an instance, it will include that identity and all instances based on the AMI will have the same identity. To ensure that the instances based on your custom AMI have a unique identity, you must remove the identity from the customized instance before creating the AMI.

#### To create a custom AMI from an AWS OpsWorks instance

1. Create a Linux stack and add one or more layers to define the configuration of the customized instance. You can use built-in layers, customized as appropriate, as well as fully custom layers. For more information, see Customizing AWS OpsWorks.
2. Edit the layers and disable AutoHealing.
3. Add an instance with your preferred Linux distribution to the layer or layers and start it. We recommend using an Amazon EBS-backed instance. Open the instance's details page and record its Amazon EC2 ID for later.
4. When the instance is online, log in with SSH and run the following commands, in order:

   1. `sudo /etc/init.d/monit stop`
   2. `sudo /etc/init.d/opsworks-agent stop`
   3. `sudo rm -rf /etc/aws/opsworks/ /opt/aws/opsworks/ /var/log/aws/opsworks/ /var/lib/aws/opsworks/ /etc/monit.d/opsworks-agent.monitrc /etc/monit/conf.d/opsworks-agent.monitrc /var/lib/cloud/`
   4. If you are creating an AMI based on Amazon Linux 2014.09, run rpm -e opsworks-agent-ruby to ensure that the agent is running.
   5. If you are creating an AMI based on Ubuntu, run dpkg -r opsworks-agent-ruby to ensure that the agent is running.
5. This step depends on the instance type:

   - For an Amazon EBS-backed instance, use the AWS OpsWorks console to stop the instance and create the AMI as described in Creating an Amazon EBS-Backed Linux AMI..
   - For an instance store-backed instance, create the AMI as described in Creating an Instance Store-Backed Linux AMI and then use the AWS OpsWorks console to stop the instance.
     When you create the AMI, be sure to include the certificate files. For example, you can call the ec2-bundle-vol command with the -i argument set to -i $(find /etc /usr /opt -name '*.pem' -o -name '*.crt' -o -name '*.gpg' | tr '\n' ','). Do not remove the apt public keys when bundling. The default ec2-bundle-vol command handles this task.
6. Clean up your stack by returning to the AWS OpsWorks console and deleting the instance from the stack.